# Alternative citation index for papers with 600+ citations?

Tags: bibliometrics

I have a memory of seeing an alternative citation index being defined, being the number of papers with more than 600 citations. In other words, something like the i10 index, but with i=600 instead.

The way I recall it, this was more or less tounge in cheek, but I think it was used by some people in the computer animation community (e.g. Ronald Fedkiw). Now, trying to look it up, I fail to find any references to this index.

Does anyone else recall seeing this, or am I mistaken?

Comment: You defined the citation index in your own question. If you feel like using it and you think it makes sense, you can just use it. It certainly is not common.